# If statement being temperamental

Tags: ios, xcode, calendar, if-statement, nsdate

I'm not sure but sometimes my if statement fails and show the wrong thing when it shouldn't be
Any ideas?

```
-(void)updateLabel{



   if (today > Date) {



    [only setHidden:YES];
    [untilRelease setHidden:YES];
    [theLabel setText:@"IS OUT"];


} else {


    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    int units = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:Date options:0];

    [theLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@, %d %@ \n %d %@, %d %@ %d %@", [components month], @"Months", [components day], @"Days", [components hour], @"Hours", [components minute], @"Minutes and", [components second], @"Seconds"]];


}}
```

I have defined today as [NSDate date] and Date is an epoch number.

Any help would be great

Comment: Just a crazy thought, but check that "today" is not released.  Replace the "today" variable with [NSDate date] -- get a new one each time -- and see if that works.

Comment: yep... do that... its weird sometimes it thinks NSDate date is past Date when it isn't :'(

Comment: my `apple > orange` statement sometimes fails to be true ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are both `NSDate` instances, do this,

```
NSComparisonResult result = [today compare:Date];
if ( result == NSOrderedDescending ){ //  today > Date
    // After Date
} else {
    // Before Date
}
```

**Original Answer**

If `today` is `[NSDate date]` and `Date` is an epoch number, you are comparing them incorrectly. You should convert `today` to epoch number too prior to comparing them.

```
long currentTime = [today timeIntervalSince1970];
if ( currentTime > Date ) {
    // After `Date`
} else {
    // Before `Date`
}
```

Comment: Date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1316476800]; i dunno what is going on :( but i use this as a refence date ;) cheers Deepak, you're the man !! *STILL DOESN'T WORK !!

Comment: @myles if they are both `NSDate` instances follow the second method.

Comment: M8 YOU'RE AMAZING AND IT WORKS PERFECTLY !! WANNA HELP ME WITH ANOTHER APP ?? ;)